# java automatic proxy configuration

Tags: java, networking, proxy, jsoup

I have written an application in jsoup that needs to connect through company proxy. I have tried giving the auto proxy config url in the java settings in control panel(XP) but it still times out the connection. What else do I need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the java environment proxy settings.

Check the [Oracle guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Answer (score 2):

Proxy settings in Java Control Panel affect only Java Web Start applications and applets.

For regular Java applications, you should use the following properties to configure proxy:

- `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, and `http.nonProxyHosts`.
- `https.proxyHost`, `https.proxyPort` (HTTPS handler uses `http.nonProxyHosts`).
- `ftp.proxyHost`, `ftp.proxyPort`, and `ftp.nonProxyHosts`.

See [Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) for more details on configuring behavior of the various classes of the java.net package.

There's no built-in way to use automatic proxy configuration for regular Java applications. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324996/does-javas-proxyselector-not-work-with-automatic-proxy-configuration-scripts) for various options to do it.