# Does Java's ProxySelector not work with automatic proxy configuration scripts?

Tags: java, proxy

I want my Java program to use the system's proxy configuration. Accordingly, I used the code found in many places, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/381698/76365), to set `java.net.useSystemProxies` to true and call `ProxySelector.getDefault().select(...)` to discover the proxy for the particular host I want to reach.  This works fine when I've configured a single explicit proxy server in Internet Properties.  But if I have set "Use automatic configuration script", it always returns the DIRECT "proxy".

I know that the script works, as my browser can access the hosts for which it returns a proxy server, and without the script set, it can't.  I even tried simplifying the script to its barest essentials:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    return "PROXY my.proxy.mydomain:3128";
}
```

and it works in my browser, but `ProxySelector.getDefault().select(...)` still returns only DIRECT.

Am I missing something?  (This is on Java 1.6 & Windows 7, should it matter.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, the Java ProxySelector does not read [Proxy Auto-Config (PAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) files.

However, [as suggested by Brian de Alwis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877497/14419) as an answer to my similar question, the **[Proxy Vole](http://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/)** library appears to provide that support/capability.

> To provide network connectivity out of the box for you Java
>   application you can use the Proxy - Vole library. It provides some
>   strategies for autodetecting the current proxy settings. There are
>   many configureable strategies to choose from. At the moment Proxy -
>   Vole supports the following proxy detection strategies.
>
> - Read platform settings (Supports: Windows, KDE, Gnome, OSX)
> - Read browser setting (Supports: Firefox 3.x, Internet Explorer; Chrome and    Webkit use the platform settings)
> - Read environment variables (often    used variables on Linux / Unix server systems)
> - **Autodetection script by using WPAD/PAC** (Not all variations supported)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Googling for "java proxy selector" doesn't find this library, unless you're sharp enough to realize that some of the code fragments going by are part of a useful library.  It's a shame Java doesn't already do it by itself, since it has the ProxySelector structure, and knows how to find an ordinary fixed proxy.

Comment: By the way, the instructions are a little misleading, in that the "default" configuration is kind of useless -- it uses the "read the java system properties" strategy, which is what you'd get without this library in the first place.  What worked for me was

    ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT);
    myProxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector();

Comment: Anyone knows about a lightweight alternative to proxy-vole? 6 MB feels a bit heavy for just some missing Java functionality.

Comment: The simplest solution happens to be to let JVM pick up the system proxies on program startup via -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies

Answer (score 15):

As already suggested by Mads Hansen, [Proxy-Vole](http://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) does the trick!

You just need to add the jar from the download site to your classpath (dlls are included) and this code helped me to configure the proxy stettings:

```
ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT); 
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.JAVA); 
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.BROWSER); 
ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector(); 

ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); 
URI home = URI.create("http://www.google.com"); 
System.out.println("ProxySelector: " + proxySelector); 
System.out.println("URI: " + home); 
List<Proxy> proxyList = proxySelector.select(home); 
if (proxyList != null && !proxyList.isEmpty()) { 
 for (Proxy proxy : proxyList) { 
   System.out.println(proxy); 
   SocketAddress address = proxy.address(); 
   if (address instanceof InetSocketAddress) { 
     String host = ((InetSocketAddress) address).getHostName(); 
     String port = Integer.toString(((InetSocketAddress) address).getPort()); 
     System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host); 
     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port); 
   } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: The code isn't working for me :(
I get NullPointerException in line List<Proxy> proxyList = proxySelector.select(home); proxySelector is null and if you look at getProxySelector() body, you'll see that it always returns null.

Comment: same for me, getProxySelector() returns NULL (but only on my Windows, on my Linux the same code works!).

Comment: The Proxy-Vole project has been dormant since 2013, but there is some activity in a fork at GitHub: https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole

Comment: @Ben do you found solution for this problem, because i add this lib and get same problem getProxySelector() returns NULL, please help because i`m stuck.

Comment: @Suspended do you found solution for this problem, because i add this lib and get same problem getProxySelector() returns NULL, please help because i`m stuck.

Comment: @deradam Why do we set env System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host); because ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); with this it work.

Comment: @Shramik good question, I do not remember to be hones as this is almost 9 years ago that I have written it. But you are right, ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); should be enough. The remaining lines however give you an idea how to access the results from the proxy selection process.

Comment: The simplest solution happens to be to let JVM pick up the system proxies on program startup via -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true as described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies

Answer (score 9):

Yes, [from version 9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170868) automatic proxy configurations (PAC/WPAD) will be read from the operating system.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Proxy Vole to solve this issue:

- Original [Google Code project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/proxy-vole/)
- More recent [GitHub project](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole), forking original

If you know exactly which PAC-file you want to use, you can do:

```
UrlPacScriptSource source = new UrlPacScriptSource("http://www.example.org/proxy.pac");
PacProxySelector selector = new PacProxySelector(source);

ProxySelector.setDefault(selector);
```

The advantage of this is that it is not user-related. For example if running this as a Windows service, you may end up running it on the SYSTEM-user which may not have the same `OS_DEFAULT` proxy settings (if any) as the Administrator-user.

The approach using system/software values is:

```
ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT);
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.BROWSER);
proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.JAVA);
ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector();

ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);
```

This starts with `OS_DEFAULT`, then `JAVA` and lastly `BROWSER` as strategies for the proxy selector.

This code is based on the GitHub code, release version 1.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

I could load Proxy Auto-Config (PAC) file on Java. Please see below codes and package.
I hope this would what you were looking for:

```
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.*;
.
.
BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();        
b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
b.setAutoConfigURL("http://yourhost/proxy.file.pac");       
DummyAutoProxyHandler handler = new DummyAutoProxyHandler();
handler.init(b);

URL url = new URL("http://host_to_query");
ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(url);     
for(ProxyInfo p : ps){
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

You already have a [com.sun.deploy.net.proxy] package on your machine! 
Find [deploy.jar] ;D

Comment: What is DummyAutoProxyHandler?