# How to use automatic proxy configuration script in Java

Tags: java, proxy, pac

My Internet Explorer is set to have an automatic proxy file(so-called PAC) for web access.  Is there a way to use this on my Java program, also ?

My below Java code does not seem to use proxy at all.

```
ArrayList<Proxy> ar = new ArrayList<Proxy>(ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://service.myurlforproxy.com")));
for(Proxy p : ar){
  System.out.println(p.toString()); //output is just DIRECT T.T it should be PROXY.
}
```

I also set my proxy script on Java Control Panel(Control->Java), but the same result.
and I found there's no way to set PAC file for Java programmatically.

People use http.proxyHost for System.setProperties(..) but this is a only for setting proxy host, not proxy script(PAC file).

Answer (score 9):

Wow! I could load Proxy Auto-Config (PAC) file on Java. Please see below codes and package.

```
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.*;
.
.
BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();        
b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
b.setAutoConfigURL("http://yourhost/proxy.file.pac");       
DummyAutoProxyHandler handler = new DummyAutoProxyHandler();
handler.init(b);

URL url = new URL("http://host_to_query");
ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(url);     
for(ProxyInfo p : ps){
    System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

You already have a [com.sun.deploy.net.proxy] package on your machine! 
Find [deploy.jar] ;D

Comment: Seems you have a DummyAutoProxyHandler class with Pixie dust on it.

Comment: could you give link to download this lib

Comment: Needed `SunAutoProxyHandler` (as in another answer) and `policy.all` file as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@jhaukur/java-proxy-pac-proxy-auto-config-f2b40e3785da). That is: `grant { permission java.security.AllPermission "", ""; };` in `policy.all` and in Java add `System.setProperty("java.security.policy" , "policy.all");`.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have any built-in support for parsing the JS PAC file. You are on your own. What you can do is download that file and parse the proxy host from it. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324996/does-javas-proxyselector-not-work-with-automatic-proxy-configuration-scripts).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I've just figured-out what the .pac file will return, then hardcode.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Jaeh answer I used the code below.
Note that **SunAutoProxyHandler** implements **AbstractAutoProxyHandler** and there is an alternative concrete implementation called **PluginAutoProxyHandler** but that implementation does not appear to be as robust:

```
    BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
    b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
    b.setAutoConfigURL("http://example.com/proxy.pac");

    SunAutoProxyHandler handler = new SunAutoProxyHandler();
    handler.init(b);

    ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(new URL(url));
    for(ProxyInfo p : ps){
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
```