# Error when try to do http GET request with proxy-vole ver.20131209

Tags: java, http, proxy

I am trying to do a HTTP GET request using proxy vole lib and I am getting this error message:

**GET request for "http://www.example.com" resulted in 505 (HTTP Version not supported).**

I am using Spring RestClient to make this request. If someone have some solution for this it will be great.

Note: I am using this snippet for making the request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604713/1785053