# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect. Have tried everything so far

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to make an https connection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    
    /*None of these worked:
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "prxgm.aknet.akb");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "prxgm.aknet.akb");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    */
    
    /*neither this helped:
    ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT); 
    ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector(); 
    ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector); 
    */

    String host = //"services.gradle.org"
            "www.yapikredi.com.tr"
            ;
    Integer port = 443;
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory
      .createSocket(host, port);
    InputStream in = sslsocket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = sslsocket.getOutputStream();

    out.write(1);
    while (in.available() > 0) {
        System.out.print(in.read());
    }

    System.out.println("Secured connection performed successfully");
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:576)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:163)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
at SSLDeneme.main(SSLDeneme.java:25)
```

I can open https://www.yapikredi.com.tr in my browser, so I think Java proxy settings are not correct.

This I've tried these without luck so far:

1. Set proxy settings using Run Configuration in eclipse: -Dhttp.proxyHost=prxgm.aknet.akb -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=prxgm.aknet.akb -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
2. Set proxy settings from the Java code as commented out in the code above.
3. 

tracert [www.yapikredi.com.tr](http://www.yapikredi.com.tr) prints:

```
Tracing route to www.yapikredi.com.tr [193.254.228.224] over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.215.144.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.215.252.3
  3     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.243.226.61
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

4. 

ping to destination time outs (ping may be disabled in our system):

```
ping www.yapikredi.com.tr
Pinging www.yapikredi.com.tr [193.254.228.224] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Ping statistics for 193.254.228.224:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

5. telnet [www.yapikredi.com.tr](http://www.yapikredi.com.tr) times out.
6. The code above, and all telnet tracert etc checks work ok for an address that by-passes proxy (a.k.a. https://www.akbank.com)
7. [Proxy-Vole](http://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) library [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10325919/1728856) didn't help either.

What else can I check?

Comment: Those `http.proxy` settings are for, err, HTTP. They have no effect on a `Socket` or `SSLSocket`. Try it with an `HttpsURLConnection`, which is what you should be using anyway for a website.

Comment: Yes HttpsURLConnection works. Dived a bit deeper to see why SSLSocket does not work but it seems beyond my expertise..

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't use those properties. `HttpsURLConnection` does not ignore them .Pretty simple. There's no reason why a socket should care about HTTP proxy settings. It doesn't know what protocol it is going to speak.